# GithubCodespaces - xdg-open not working for html files

Tags: elixir, alpine-linux, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces

Currently we are using Github Codespaces as part of our development flow (via VSCode Local) and on the language that we are running our app (Elixir), we have a command called `open_browser(view)` that should open a screenshot of the current UI on some test.

This base container run as Alpine Linux.

Previously, when we were running full local, it should open this screenshot on Chrome and expose to the developer to find out what is happening for this test.

With Codespaces, when we perform the same command nothing happens.

I have done a debug and find out that what this command do is:

`xdg-open /tmp/PATH_TO_FILE.html`

If i try `xdg-open "https://google.com.br"` it works fine.
if i try `xdg-open "PATH_TO_FILE"` nothing happends.

Do someone knows how we can handle this?

Maybe start a firefox/browser service in parallel with the app and make the xdg-open pointing there?

Thanks a lot!

I have tried to install into our codespaces via docker-compose a instance of a firefox
Tried to tune xdg-open as well, with no success.

Comment: Have you tried it with Chrome? I've had varying experiences with `xdg-open` and Firefox.

Comment: @DogEatDog Yeah, with no success as well :/